# libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll contains an error

Tags: octave, libgcc

I have been using Octave 4.03 for about a year on Windows 10 platform.
All at a sudden, when I was trying to launch Octave GUI as usual, I recieved the following error message:

> File libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact administrator. Error status: 0xc0000020.

Any help how to fix this problem?

Comment: As the error message says, try installing the program again

Comment: Please copy the mentioned dll, den make a fresh install and compare the original and the newly installed dll. If they differ (although you've used the same installer) this might be a sign for a virus/trojan infection or damaged harddrive or memory.

Comment: See [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/receive-error-status-0xc0000020-for-most/b6ff214f-57dd-4754-beb3-5efe5f75f4c4) on answers.microsoft.com